# Spring Boot Validation of Path Variables returns blank message

Tags: spring, spring-boot, validation, message

I'm using spring boot validation to validate the @PathVariable as shown in the code below,  the validation works however there is no message returned when I execute through curl.exe,  I expect to receive the default message.

```
  @GetMapping("/number/{id}")
  String getNumber(@PathVariable @Min(2) Long id) {
        System.out.println("getNumber :" + id);
    return "param id is : " + id;
  }
```

I have specified a CustomGlobalExceptionHandler to catch ConstraintViolationException and this works in that the returned http status code is 400 and it displays a message in the console log "*must be greater than or equal to 2*"

```
@ExceptionHandler(ConstraintViolationException.class)
@ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST)
@ResponseBody
void onConstraintValidationException(ConstraintViolationException e) {
  System.out.println("in onConstraintValidationException - start");
    String error = "blank";
  for (ConstraintViolation<?> violation : e.getConstraintViolations()) {
      error = violation.getMessage();
      System.out.println(error);
  }
  System.out.println("in onConstraintValidationException - end");
}
```

I'm using the command line to execute the REST Service
curl.exe -v -X GET "http://localhost:8080/demo-0.0.2-SNAPSHOT/number/1" -H "accept: */*"

and I receive this output,  but no message

```
*Note: Unnecessary use of -X or --request, GET is already inferred.
*   Trying ::1...
* TCP_NODELAY set
* Connected to localhost (::1) port 8080 (#0)
> GET /demo-0.0.2-SNAPSHOT/number/1 HTTP/1.1
> Host: localhost:8080
> User-Agent: curl/7.55.1
> accept: */*
>
< HTTP/1.1 400
< Transfer-Encoding: chunked
< Date: Tue, 11 Aug 2020 09:28:06 GMT
< Connection: close
<
* Closing connection 0*
```

I based this on the mykong.com example  https://mkyong.com/spring-boot/spring-rest-validation-example/ section 3. Path Variables Validation.  where the results should match

```
curl -v localhost:8080/books/0

{
    "timestamp":"2019-02-20T13:35:59.808+0000",
    "status":400,
    "error":"Bad Request",
    "message":"findOne.id: must be greater than or equal to 1",
    "path":"/books/0"
}
```

Can you suggest why I don't receive a message returned back to the command line?

Comment: Ofcourse you don't receive a message, you aren't sending a message only a status, so how should the client receive a message? Also you are comparing different things in regarding the error being shown (and you are overriding the default exception handling mechanism so that doesn't apply anymore).

Comment: how do you suggest I send the message.  I reverted back to the code suggested by @ACV, but still no message. I already tried a custom message `@Min(value = 2, message = "2 is the minimum value")`  but this is not displayed either.

Answer (score 0):

Did you add these annotations to your controller:

```
import org.springframework.validation.annotation.Validated;
import javax.validation.constraints.Min;

@RestController
@Validated
```

You have to implement this class in order to get 400 message instead of 500:

```
@ControllerAdvice
public class CustomGlobalExceptionHandler extends ResponseEntityExceptionHandler {

    @ExceptionHandler(ConstraintViolationException.class)
    public void constraintViolationException(HttpServletResponse response) throws IOException {
        response.sendError(HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST.value());
    }

    //..
}
```

Comment: yes both @RestController & @Validated are added to the controller.  I changed the CustomGlobalExceptionHandler as you have suggested and the commandl ine output is slightly different.`{"timestamp":"2020-08-11T11:09:26.812+00:00","status":400,"error":"Bad Request","message":"","path":"/demo-0.0.2-SNAPSHOT/number/1"}* Closing connection 0` .  But the message is still blank.